# Disqus comment count issue on angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, disqus

I have installed disqus comments system on my angular website perfectly through this documentation http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/34/using-disqus-with-angularjs. It works just fine but when I'am adding `disqus` comment count system on my homepage via script given here https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page, it is showing 0 comments on my homepage that too after refreshing and it goes back to not showing after i enter and exit from the page where comment widget it.

I have added comment count like this,

```html
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/blog/#disqus_thread" class="comments">< /a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved: Disqus Comment Count System does not works properly on localserver as domain registration is must for disqus-url variable.... just got a domain and it works like a charm!